# Removing white space from the beginning using regular expression in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to get the data from a website using php curl. From the output, I need to neglect all the white spaces and empty lines. I used some regex. I'm really not familiar with Regex.

Please help me solve this problem.

There is my code:

```
if(preg_match('/<div class="search-results-details-body">(.*?) <div class="search-results-details-footer">/s', $result, $output))
{
    $stripped_result = ltrim(strip_tags($output[1]));
    $refined_output = str_replace('  ','',$stripped_result); 
    $regex = preg_replace('[\n\n]', "\n", $refined_output);  exit();
}
```

and this is my output in order:

```
 Requirements
  Minimum 2 years of web development experience is required
  Experience with PHP, MySQL, HTML, CSS, and JavaScript are preferred
  Bachelors Degree in Computer Science or related field
  Full knowledge and experience of software development lifecycle
  Strong organisational and analytical skills
  Ability to work under pressure to meet deadlines and required quality standards
  Ability to multi-task and prioritize responsibilities
  Excellent oral and written communication skills
```

here i want to remove all the starting white spaces.
i need to get the output like this :

```
  Requirements
  Minimum 2 years of web development experience is required
  Experience with PHP, MySQL, HTML, CSS, and JavaScript are preferred
  Bachelors Degree in Computer Science or related field
  Full knowledge and experience of software development lifecycle
  Strong organisational and analytical skills
  Ability to work under pressure to meet deadlines and required quality standards
  Ability to multi-task and prioritize responsibilities
  Excellent oral and written communication skills
```

Please suggest a good solution

Thank you

Comment: [`ltrim()`](http://ch1.php.net/ltrim) might be better. ;)

Comment: if you want to remove all the starting whitespaces then use this regex `preg_replace('^ *', "", $string);`

Comment: use trim it will remove spaces and special characters from begning and end.

Answer (score 5):

> i want to remove all the starting white spaces, i need to neglect all the white spaces and empty lines.

Just replace with empty string

```
^\s+
```

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/kR1eR4/1)

- `^` matches start of the line/string
- `\s` matches any white space character `[\r\n\t\f ]`

---

Sample code:

```
$re = "/^\\s+/m";
$result = preg_replace($re, '', $str);
```